# How should I reply to a comment which is a request for code?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, comments, answers

In a comments discussion I was asked in a comment to share my code. Unfortunately the code exceeds the number of characters allowed in the comment. I'm not a question owner nor the answer.

Comment: So why were you asked for code, if it wasn't your answer or question? If your codes answers the question, along with a description of how and why your code answers the question, you can add it as an answer.

Comment: I commented the answer, where I explained that the answer doesn't work for me. The onwer of that answer asked me to share a code.

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask a question yourself then. Mention the answer, why it doesn't work for you, and what code you use

Comment: Also make sure you have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Don't just dump *all* of the irrelevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are the poster of a question or answer:**

Click the Edit button on your post to include the code. Make sure your code is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

**If you commented on a post, and were asked to provide more details:**

If you for example commented on an answer because you can't get it to work you should ask a new question. In your question make sure you include your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), provide a reference to the answer you couldn't get to work and also don't forget to mention what problem you are trying to solve, because you might be falling into an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).
You can also leave a comment to the original answer you have problems with linking your new question to alert the poster of the answer.